# SQL full outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am busy completing an old examiniation paper

One question reads as follows:

Study the following tables and answer the questions below:

```
CREATE TABLE CARDHOLDERS(
CH_ID INTEGER IDENTITY,
CH_NAME VARCHAR(50),
CH_SURNAME VARCHAR(50),
CH_IDNUMBER CHAR(13),
CH_CARDNUMBER CHAR(13),
CH_STATUS CHAR(2),
CH_CREATE_DATE DATETIME,
CH_LAST_CHANGE_DATE DATETIME)

CARDHOLDER_STATUS //apologies if this is wrongly formatted 
CHS_STATUS  CHS_DESCRIPTION
00          Active
01          Not Active
```

***Write a query to obtain the following results***

```
Cardholder  Status
Ashton, T   Active
Brown, C    Active
Crawford, C Not Active
Ellis, J    Active
```

I assume I will have to make use of a full outer join since no colum matches in the two tables.
I wrote this piece of code, but it is giving me a syntax error.

```
SELECT CH_NAME, CH_SURNAME
FROM CARDHOLDERS
FULL OUTER JOIN 
ON CARDHOLDER_STATUS.CHS_STATUS, CARDHOLDER_STATUS.CHS_DESCRIPTION
```

- Am I on the right path or is my logic completely wrong?
- Am I right in using a outer join, any alternative join I could use?
- How can I extract only the first letter from CH_NAME to use as an
  initial?

Comment: Can you not simply join on `CH_STATUS = CHS_STATUS`?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing example data, I would expect he followign to "just work":

```
SELECT      ch.CH_SURNAME + ', ' + LEFT(ch.CH_NAME, 1) AS Cardholder,
            chs.CHS_DESCRIPTION AS Status

FROM        CARDHOLDERS AS ch

INNER JOIN  CARDHOLDER_STATUS AS chs
    ON      chs.CHS_STATUS = ch.CH_STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   SELECT CH_NAME+','+ CH_SURNAME,CHS_Description
    FROM CARDHOLDERS C
    JOIN  CARDHOLDER_STATUS  S on S.CHS_STATUS = C.CH_STATUS
```